# How to connect a capacitor (high pass 1st order) to a tweeter in series with a full-range speaker?

Tags: capacitor, filter, high-pass-filter

I've hit a bit of a snag with my stereo project.

I have a 2-channel amplifier from eBay, and I've been using it with 4 ohm speakers, one on each channel.

Now I planned to upgrade it with tweeters. I got a 3.9uF capacitor for my tweeters, thinking of connecting it in parallel. I got a set of tweeters of 8 ohms each.

I realized something.

Connecting my 4 ohm speaker and 8ohm tweeter (tweeter in series with a capacitor) in parallel, results in a net resistance of 2.67 Ohms and will cause a problem for my amplifier.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8DpuD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

It seems putting these two speakers in series will be better as it will give a net impedance of 12 ohms. But where/how can I connect the capacitor (as a high-pass filter) for my tweeter?

Any other way I could proceed with this?

I saw a method to do it in series:

[image]

But I do NOT have a low pass filter (I assume an inductor.) It would be better, because I don't have the time to procure other components :(

Comment: how do U know it is a problem in shunt?  Series is a bigger problem.

Comment: u need 2 LC pairs nonpolar

Comment: Always start with a spec. ! How you want power to be shared, breakpoints, peaking (Q), overall impedance (f) ok, got it?  or if you prefer, passband loss at f, stop band loss at f for each.  Crossover f. ok?

Comment: I made this for you http://tinyurl.com/ya388rzl

Comment: what you have should be fine if you run it at slightly reduced volume levels.

Answer (score 2):

If you are worried about overloading the amplifier then I wouldn't be overly concerned unless you were intent on playing very loud passages of sound that were exclusively in the low to mid kHz region (not something that normal or even modern music attempts to do).

The 3.9 uF capacitor starts to "bring-in" the tweeter at a few kHz and above so if you are really worried about loading then consider putting an inductor in series with your woofer so that as frequency rises, the woofer is progressively removed from circuit. Something about 1 mH should start reducing the loading effect of the woofer from about 1 kHz upwards.

Alternatively, find one of the several web-site tools that calculates proper cross-over components values and do the job properly.

> I don't have the time to procure other components

Sometimes, you just can't make a silk purse from a sow's ear

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It looks like I'll just buy a new set of speakers.

I'll probably take your advice on the Series Inductor. 

BTW - do you feel a 3.9uF capacitor is enough for a tweeter? Would you recommend going for a 2nd order High Pass Filter? Not that it's an expensive tweeter, but it's also nice to know. :)

Comment: The capacitor needs to be selected with respect to the tweeters impedance. I would say on this occasion that if I assume the tweeter is 8 ohm then 3.9 uF is a little low but there are good website calculators that can provide values. Thanks are appreciated but even more so when an answer is formally accepted.

Comment: 3.9uF and 8ohm makes for a corner frequency of 5.1kHz which is sort of on the high side for most tweeters.  Formally making for just 6dB/octave (which does not protect a lot against lower frequencies), this will significantly interact with the impedance response of the tweeter.  It's usual for cone tweeter high passes to rather aim for 12dB/oct and for horn tweeters for 18dB/oct.  Woofers tend to be cut off using 12dB/oct.  The latter is not for protecting the speaker but avoiding bad directivity/impulse response for high frequencies.

Answer (score 0):

Usually cabinet and P.A manufacturers (as Peavey , Ashdown , D.A.S) solve this problem with a 10 Ohm  serial resistor to one of the tweeter terminals. It would be a big one; for example, a 2 watt resistor.

Comment: That's for piezo tweeters.  It's not "solving" an impedance problem but smoothing the frequency response, addressing some of the "piezo harshness".  For an actual dynamic tweeter with 8ohm impedance, a 2W resistor will not get you anywhere useful.

Answer (score 0):

use two 8 ohm speakers to equal 4 ohms.  For the tweeter use 4.7 or two 2.2 in parallel.